Proving weighted variant of Kőnig's/Egerváry theorem
I am having trouble with the following problem I came across:

Let $G = (A, B, E)$ be a bipartite graph with weights $w \colon E \rightarrow \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$. We write $\nu_{w}'(G)$ for the maximum weighted matching in $G$ and write $\tau_{w}'(G)$ for the size of the minimum $w$-weighted vertex cover with non-negative values in $G$. Show that $\nu_{w}'(G) = \tau_{w}'(G)$.

Note that $\nu_{w}'(G)$ and $\tau_{w}'(G)$ differ slightly from the usual, hence the similarity in notation. We have that $\nu_{w}'(G)$, unlike $\nu_{w}(G)$, denotes the maximum weighted matching (not perfect matching) in $G$. We also have that $\tau_{w}'(G)$, unlike $\tau_{w}(G)$, is restricted to the minimum vertex cover with non-negative values in $G$.
I am familiar with the following result due to Egerváry:

Let $G$ be a bipartite graph with edge weights $w \colon E \rightarrow \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$ and suppose that $G$ has a perfect matching. Then $v_{w}(G) = \tau_{w}(G)$.

Because of the similarity with my problem I thought of distinguishing between a few cases. Clearly, if $v_{w}'(G) = v_{w}(G)$ and $\tau_{w}'(G) = \tau_{w}(G)$ then $v_{w}'(G) = \tau_{w}'(G)$. But this doesn't seem like the right approach in the remaining cases.
I thought of proving two inequalities, one of which clearly holds: $v'_{w}(G) \leq \tau_{w}'(G)$, but I'm unsure how to show the other one.
Any help is appreciated.
Edit: By a $w$-weighted vertex cover I mean a function $\pi \colon V= A \cup B \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that for all $\{u, v\} \in E$ we have $\pi(u) + \pi(v) \geq w(\{u, v\})$.
The size of vertex cover $\pi$ equals $\sum_{v\in V} \pi(v)$.

@MishaLavrov Yes it is

Also, are you happy with a solution via linear programming, or are you looking for a combinatorial argument?

@MishaLavrov  I am looking for a combinatorial argument.
